# Surface Pro stylus and touch behavior after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, touchscreen, surface, stylus

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 in Surface Pro. Everything works fine, but the stylus and touch behaves in an undesired way. Moving my finger or stylus around the screen automatically selects files and folders, by creating a rectangle, as if I am pressing the left click button of the mouse permanently.

I will be very grateful, if anyone could suggest how I can correct this type of undesired behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the correct behavior.. what are you expecting?

Comment: If you mean scrolling up and down with fingers and things like that, it seems that not all software manages that. I know that most Gnome projects do (Web works nicely whereas Firefox and Chromium struggle with it).

As for files, in general that is how it behaves but I *think* nautilus is working fine with touch.